# Cannot get TxTextControl dialog to use language translation from my sattelite assembly resource

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

When I call txTextcontrol.FontDialog() or any of the other built-in dialogs that come with TXTextControl for Windows Forms, it does not use the localized language, only the default English one.

I have created my own resource file for TXTextControl dialogs using the procedure outlined here: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_techarticle_resourcekit.htm
I seem to have correctly generated a txtextcontrol.resources.dll file for the Norwegian language (nb-NO) and have placed the file in my src\bin\Debug\nb-NO directory. The other dlls and exe files are in src\bin\Debug.
I also have set current culture like this

```
CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

When I run this from Visual Studio, my own application's localized resource is loaded and used, but not this one. Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was creating assemblies for .net 4.0 instead of 3.5 as I was using.